# laravel - How to put a content to a *.blade.php file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I put a content to `*.blade.php` file. I already try some different way but my `*.blade.php` still blank.

```
$file = 'hienthi.blade.php';

$current = file_get_contents($file);

$current .= $request->code; // Get a content from $request->code

File::put($file, $current);
```

or

```
$fp = fopen('hienthi.blade.php', 'w');

fwrite($fp, $request->code); // Get a content from $request->code

fclose($fp);
```

My `hienthi.blade.php` is still blank when I use 2 ways above.

Seems like `file_put_content` function just work with txt file ?

Is there anyway to put a content to `*.blade.php` file ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe permissions issue?

Comment: @S.I. I think it's not permissions issue because I set 777 permission to all project to test that. But it's still not work.

Comment: Check you cache for view files?

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents($file)` will work only when you are this in `views`

but you can achieve this in the controller like this

```
$file = 'hienthi';

$current = view($file)->render();

$current .= $request->code; // Get a content from $request->code

File::put($file, $current);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: It's still not work :( My blade is still blank. Nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the address of the file. Your `$file` variable doesn't contain the location of the actual `blade` file in the views directory.

You should do the following:

```
 $file = resource_path() . "views/hienthi.blade.php"; 
 //resource_path() is helper function to return path to resources directory
```

And you should prefer to use `Storage` class for the manipulation.

```
 Storage::get(...)
 Storage::put(...)
```

I couldn't test this because I am travelling. I'll update this answer once I get the chance. Refer to official [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files) for the file storage explanation.

Comment: Still not working :( Nothings happens in my blade file. I already clear cache but it's not help. I will research more about Storage in official doc. Thank you.